# disable dropdownlist option after selection asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to disable my dropdownlist after a user select the droopdownlist. So, if the user enter this page, the user only lead to

1. dropdownlist when they have not choose before
2. the selected item value if they have choose before, but they can not select again (means: it disabled)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7uYT.png

because every selected item here will trigger some calculation to the next page.

Do you have any tutorial to do this? Or can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `DowpDownList`'s `AutoPostBack` property to `true` and handle the `SelectedIndexChanged`-event. There you can disable it:

```
protected void Ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) sender;
    ddl.Enabled = false;
    // store the SelectedValue somewhere, f.e. in the Session
    // or Response.Redirect to the next page and pass it via url-parameter
}
```